# Probability - discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a particular group of people, 10 people are right handed and 4 are left handed. If 5 of these people are chosen at random, What is the probability that exactly 1 left handed person is selected?

I got 240,240 for all the possible outcomes. Can someone give me a hint to find if 1 left handed person is selected?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hypergeometric distribution. We begin with choosing a single left handed person. This is independent of choosing four right-handed people, so by rule of product we multiply. We divide by the number of ways to select 5 people.

$$
\frac{ \binom{4}{1} \binom{6}{4} } { \binom{10}{5} }
$$